# What does ''empirical bite'' mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

''Whether computationalism has empirical bite depends on how we construe the notion of computation. ''

I am having trouble understanding this. What does it mean? I checked the phrase itself (empirical bite) and then checked the word itself (bite) since there might be some uncommon meanings of the word that I did not know, but nothing fits the context. I have an idea that ''empirical bite'' may mean something like ''empirically testable'', but I am helpless right now.

Comment: Bite means significance or power, similar to *This contract has no teeth in it*.

Comment: I really thank you.

Comment: I think your intuition that it has to do with testability is good. I read the sentence as concerning itself with the existence of practical consequences of "computationalism"

Comment: I'm guessing that there's a pun in there somewhere.

Comment: Yeah dude, we worship calculators lmao.

Comment: Source: https://www.umsl.edu/~piccininig/Computationalism_in_the_Philosophy_of_Mind.pdf. This is heavy stuff and it is virtually impossible to pick out a sentence and make sense of it.

Comment: I have a background in cognitive science. This is jargon and won't make much sense to people outside the field. I'd ask on a cognition site, the standard interpretation of english won't apply well here.

Answer (score 3):

If something has "bite" it means it has a real effect, makes a difference.

If something is "empirical" it means it is measurable, objectively verifiable.

So something that has "empirical bite" means it makes a difference in a measurable sense.

Comment: In fact, I saw the ''effect'' meaning of the word 'bite' in internet dictionaries, but does it really fit the context? Yosef Basin above said it means ''significance''. With this, it makes sense. I mean, ''Whether computationalism has empirical significance (bite) depends on how we construe the notion of computation'' works. But, ''Whether computationalism has empirical effect...'' is not clear. Having empirical effect does not seem to be working, I guess.

Comment: Think of consequence(s) as a synonym for effect: having empirical bite can mean having empirical consequences.